# i need to know whats the diference between from tkinter import * and from tkinter import 'module'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I am learnig python for the beginning, I am doing some tutorials and video-tutorials. I am using sublime text 3 for wrinting code and the console of sublimeREPL to run the files and the code. 
a few days ago I had to search on the web how to make sublimeREPL to run as IDLE 3 runs, and i made it.

The problem right now is that in the lesson i am doing right now they are teaching me how to use tkinter but in the videos the guy codes:

```
from tkinter import *
colorchooser.askcolor()
```

and it works, but when i code that , it doesn't work. the error says:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in 
>   NameError: name 'colorchooser' is not defined

I need to code :

```
from tkinter import colorchooser
colorchooser.askcolor()
```

and it works.

I just need to know why do I have to do it like this?, and why doesn't it work for me in the first way?

I not a English Speaker I tried my best.

Comment: Seems like the python version in video is different (probably older) than yours. Does this work for you: `from tkinter import *` `tkinter.colorchooser.askcolor()`?
Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tkinter.html.

Comment: Which video where you watching?

Comment: the version on de video it is 3.3.3 and i usin 3.4.3, i tried if form tkinter import * tkinter.colorchooser.askcolor() and it doesn't work--> NameError: name 'tkinter' is not defined

Comment: Also i realize that if I run the first one on the IDLE 3  it works . I understand all your answers but this confuses me xD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
from tkinter import colorchooser
```

you are importing the (sub-)**module** `colorchooser` (plus its variables and functions) from the [**package**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) (which is a structured module) `tkinter`.

> Packages are a way of structuring Python’s module namespace by using “dotted module names”.

So the module `tkinter` is structured as follows:

```
tkinter/
    colorchooser/
        askcolor()
        ...
```

With `from tkinter import *` you are [importing all **methods** and **variables**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) from `tkinter` (in fact all public objects not starting with `_`), **but not its submodules**, this is why the two methods are not the same:

> ... the statement `from sound.effects import *` does not import all submodules from the package sound.effects into the current namespace

([source](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package))

You can, however (even though many would say `from ... import *` is bad practice)

```
from tkinter.colorchooser import *
```

Answer (score 0):

from tkinter import * doesn't work because you need the entire tkinter directory. 
This is why you must specificy colorchooser module for your program to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you saw that , but `colorchooser` has always been a module inside `tkinter` and it does not get imported when you do -

```
from tkinter import *
```

You have to specifically import it using -

```
from tkinter import colorchooser
```

As you already observed.